# Static ID works in JS but doesn't work if I take value from Apex Controller?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, lightning-datatable

I want to have pre-selected checkbox for inline editing in Lightning:dataTable tag. So if I am using hard-coded value for ID (i.e. static value) to set value for selectedRows attribute (regarding Lightning:dataTable attribute), but same does not work If I take ID value from Apex Controller. I think this is some JSON Parsing error.

*This is working:*

```
var selectedRowsIds = ["003K000001Kul79IAB"];
component.set("v.selectedRows", selectedRowsIds);
```

*But this is not working:*

```
var newContID = component.get("v.wrapperDataRec.conID");
component.set("v.selectedRows", newContID);
```

**JS CODE:**

```
var action = component.get("c.getOpptyData");
action.setParams({"OpptyId" : component.get("v.recordId")});
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
    if(state==="SUCCESS"){         
        component.set("v.wrapperDataRec",response.getReturnValue());

        //Pre-selected checkbox for one Conatct Record

        var selectedRowsIds = ["003K000001Kul79IAB"];
        component.set("v.selectedRows", newContID);
        //   }
    }
```

Where I am doing wrong in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where your newContID is being set, but presumably, you didn't make it an Array. Try:

```
component.set("v.selectedRows", [newContID]);
```

This will make a new Array with a single element in it, just like the hard-coded ID example.

Comment: Don’t forget to accept the answer